# When saving data into the database an error occurs in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I'm new to Laravel and need some help. When I hit `$assignment->save()` in my laragon terminal I get the following error.

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list'
>   (SQL: insert into `assignments` (`body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('assignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();[enter image description here][1]
        $table->text('body');
        $table->boolean('completed')->default(false);
        $table->timestamp('due_date')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, Eloquent expects the columns `created_at` & `updated_at` in your tables. In your model(s), please set the `$timestamps` property to false to disable this functionality.

```php
public $timestamps = false;
```